How to differentiate MF4 data between networks of same type
I am using asammdf to read an MF4 file containing data from at least two networks. Usually there's a LIN network, for which an LDF is also available (signal names can be used to extract data), and a CAN network that contains (a lot of) sensor logging data. For the CAN network I do not have a database because I'm using CAN-FD and the DLC is variable for bandwidth optimization purposes, so I have to process the raw frame data.
In this scenario I can do the following:
mdf = MDF(tracePath)
# Read LIN signals
for s in Config.Common.Canoe.Signals:
   sig = mdf.get_lin_signal(name=s, database=ldfPath)
   print(sig.timestamps)
   print(sig.samples)

# Read data of CAN frames
data = mdf.get("CAN_DataFrame.DataBytes")
print(data.timestamps)
print(data.samples)

# Read IDs of CAN frames
ids = mdf.get("CAN_DataFrame.ID")
print(ID.timestamps)
print(ID.samples)

This works fine. My problem is what to do in the scenario when the LIN network is replaced by another CAN network. In this case I would have two CAN networks, one also containing a database for processing signals and the other one still containing the logging data that I described earlier. How can I differentiate between the two CAN networks in this case?
I tried using the network name when getting the data, but this is not supported:
   data = mdf.get("CAN1.CAN_DataFrame.DataBytes")
   ids = mdf.get("CAN1.CAN_DataFrame.ID")

